# TableView-keyboard animation issue with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a tableView inside a view. Below tableView is a toolbar(with textField in it) and below that is the tabbar. This screen is basically for chatting.

I change view's height when keyboard is displayed (decreasing the height) and also when hidden (increasing the height back to original). It works fine when keyboard is displayed.

Issue is when keyboard is hidden, tableView goes little up with a jerk.

The issue is not with the view's animation because when I put delay in animation, then also tableView goes up with jerk right away (even before view animation has started).

**When keyboard is displayed :**

[image]

**While hiding keyboard :**

[image]

**Code to animate decrease in height when keyboard is being displayed (THIS WORKS FINE) :**

```
    // Remove constraint from view
    // Change constraint constant
    // Add constraint to view
    .
    .
    .

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];

    // If at least one chat message
    if ([chatData count] != 0)
    {
        [chatTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([chatData count] - VALUE_ONE) inSection:VALUE_ZERO] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    }
```

**Code to animate increase in height when keyboard is being hidden :**

```
    // Remove constraint from view
    // Change constraint constant
    // Add constraint to view
    .
    .
    .

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Do you perform any scrolling or changing table view insets when dismissing a keyboard?

Comment: @vokilam Please look at my code. TableView constraints are set such that its width, origin are same as `view`. And height is some points less than `view`.

Comment: I see. I tried to reproduce this issue on ios 7 - unsuccessfully. What are are constraints between table view, toolbar and superview?

Comment: @vokilam For tableView and superView please see my previous comment. For tableView and toolbar, they have vertical spacing of 0pt. toolbar is below tableView.

Comment: @vokilam See my update. I could found the reason.

Comment: I'm still not sure about constraints. _Exact_ constraints could be: leading, top and trailing space from table view to superview equals zero; leading, bottom and trailing space from toolbar to superview equals zero; vertical space between table and toolbar equals zero.

Comment: @vokilam Yes, it is exactly the same. I have tabbar below the toolbar. So for toolbar vertical splace with tabbar is 0. For tabbar, leading, trailing, bottom to superview is 0. BTW, Ignore my question update. TableView's top to superview is 0 so its origin.y has to be 0 only.

Comment: @Geek - Keep in mind when you are using autolayout, you can't set frame else you have weird results - try work with constraints only or else turn off autolayout

Comment: @bhavyakothari Tried setting frame. Still not working. Updated question description and code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that it was due to change in height of tableView. I was decreasing and increasing it when keyboard is displayed. Also I was scrolling the cells through code using below method, which was changing `contentOffset` and it was causing jerk.

```
[chatTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([chatData count] - 1) inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

The solution is to not to change height of tableView and use below code.

**When keyboard is displayed :**

```
// Change table contentInset
UIEdgeInsets contentInset = self.chatTable.contentInset;
contentInset.bottom = keyboardHeight;

UIEdgeInsets scrollIndicatorInsets = self.chatTable.scrollIndicatorInsets;
scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = keyboardHeight;

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    self.chatTable.contentInset = contentInset;
    self.chatTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollIndicatorInsets;
}];

// Optional : Display last cell with animation
if ([chatData count] != 0)
{
    [chatTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([chatData count] - 1) inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

**When keyboard is hidden :**

```
// Reset table contentInset
UIEdgeInsets contentInset = self.chatTable.contentInset;
contentInset.bottom = 0.0f;

UIEdgeInsets scrollIndicatorInsets = self.chatTable.scrollIndicatorInsets;
scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 0.0f;

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    self.chatTable.contentInset = contentInset;
    self.chatTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollIndicatorInsets;
}];

// Optional : Display last cell with animation
if ([chatData count] != 0)
{
    [chatTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([chatData count] - 1) inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of changing the frame, just set the content inset when your keyboard appears and when the keyboard is hidden use the content offset of table.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, heightOfYourKeyboardAndStuff, 0.0);
[tableView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0.0, -heightOfYourKeyboardAndStuff) animated: YES];
```

&

```
[tableView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0.0, preferedValue) animated: YES];
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

I think it should work fine and smooth.

Answer (score 1):

instead of changing the frame animated you should adjust the tableView's contentInset / contentOffset when displaying keyboard

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, heightOfYourKeyboardAndStuff, 0.0);
[tableView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0.0, -heightOfYourKeyboardAndStuff) animated: YES];
```

and vice versa when hiding the keyboard

```
[tableView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0.0, preferedValue) animated: YES];
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

in my experirience this works very smoothly! calculate heightOfYourKeyboardAndStuff and preferedValue with custom arithmetics to fit it to your needs.

ps: you might need to store / restore the current contentOffset before showing / after hiding the keyboard.

Comment: This will not work, because constraints are such that `tableView` and `view` must have same origin and width. And height is some fixed points less than `view`'s height.

Comment: this would work although you set your constraints, because neither the frame of the view nor the frame of the tableView is touched. it's only the scrollView which is "inside" the tableView which is being modified by my code

Comment: I need to change `view`'s height. Otherwise when keyboard is displayed, textfield will not be visible. It would be behind the keyboard. Thus, I have to decrease view's height so that textField is visible.

Comment: you don't need to. because you could easily place your textfield over the tableView right above the keyboard so that textField and keyboard cover your tableView whose content is inset at the bottom by the amount of pixels both frame's heights take. that's good practise and avoids the problem with layout constraints and jumpiness animation.

Comment: `contentOffset` is having no effect. And `contentInset` works, but it is changing scroll bounds sharply. If there is a way to animate that then my problem will be solved.

Comment: you need to set both contentInset and contentOffset (animated). the code provided in my answer works perfectly in my app. I used it to shift textFields withing a scrollView if they would have been covered by the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

having this issue in Xamarin when adding fixed height for the ListView Solve it by adding custom renderer then

```
 UIKit.UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow((sender, args) =>
            {
                //to extend the space between your content and the edges
                Control.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0,0,0,0);
            });
            UIKit.UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide((sender, args) =>
            {
                Control.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0,0,0,0);
            });
```